# FileDescriptor to open a file in Java

Tags: java

I want to have a method whose purpose is this :

`fileDescriptor openFile (filename)` : will open a file with a specific name (it will erase the content if it already exists) and put a “Beginning of Process” as a first line); return a file descriptor

```
public FileDescriptor openFile(String fileName){
}
```

Can anybody help me wd this?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow. To prevent your question from being closed, explain [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and where you are stuck.

Comment: Why do you think you need it to return a `FileDescriptor?` You don't.

Comment: IMHO `FileDescriptor` is for internal use only, you don't want to be playing with it.

Answer (score 8):

here is how to do it:

```
private FileDescriptor openFile(String path)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File file = new File(path);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    // remember th 'fos' reference somewhere for later closing it
    fos.write((new Date() + " Beginning of process...").getBytes());
    return fos.getFD();
}
```

However, it is better to return FileOutputStream instance (from which you can get FileDescriptor as well), because you can then add more content to file and properly close it

If your method signature does not allow for exceptions, try-catch and throw RuntimeException
or try-catch exceptions and return null (in that case, add javadoc explaining what returned null means)

Comment: when try this function to access tty file 
return /dev/tty: open failed: ENXIO (No such device or address) 
can help me for fix this issue ?