# FileDescriptor of Directory in Java

Tags: java, directory, file-descriptor

is there a way to open a directory stream in Java like in C? I need a FileDescriptor of an opened directory. Well, actually just the number of the fd.

I try to implement a checkpoint/restore functionality in Java with the help of CRIU link. To do this, I need to deploy a RPC call to the CRIU service. There I have to provide the integer value of the FD of an already opened directory, where the image files of the process will be stored.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Guess that in this case we need more details in what you would like to accomplish.
Needless to say that java has a way more handled approach to I/O then c.

Comment: What is a directory stream?

Comment: I try to implement a checkpoint/restore functionality in Java with the help of CRIU [link](http://criu.org/Main_Page). To do this, I need to deploy a RPC call to the CRIU service. There I have to provide the integer value of the FD of an already opened directory, where the image files of the process will be stored.

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way to open a directory stream in Java like in C?

No there isn't.  Not without resorting to native code.

If you want to "read" a directory in (pure) Java, you can do it using one of the following:

- `File.list()` - gives you the names of the directory entries as strings.
- `File.list(FilenameFilter)` - ditto, but only directory entries that match are returned.
- `File.listFiles()` - like `list()` but returning `File` objects.
- etcetera
- `Files.newDirectoryStream(Path)` gives you an iterator for the `Path` objects for the entries in a directory.

The last one could be "close" to what you are trying to achieve, but it does not entail  application code getting hold of a file descriptor for a directory, or the application doing a low-level "read" on the directory.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need FD in Java. All you need is a reference to that file which you can simply acquire using `File file = new File("PathToYourFile");`

To read/write you have Streams in Java. You can use

```
    BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("myFile.txt")));
    PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File("myFile.txt")));
```

Even directory is a file. You can use `isDirectory()` on file object to check if it is a directory or a file.

Answer (score -2):

```
private FileDescriptor openFile(String path)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File file = new File(path);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    // remember th 'fos' reference somewhere for later closing it
    fos.write((new Date() + " Beginning of process...").getBytes());
    return fos.getFD();
}
```

Comment: This does not work if your path is pointing to a directory, which is asked for.

Comment: Looks like a copy and paste from [stackoverflow.com/a/11881428](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11881428).

Comment: This answers how to get a descriptor for a file. The question was how to get a descriptor for a directory.